# Remove GMAIL Account programmatically

Tags: android, gmail

How to remove all GMAIL Accounts available in the Device, programmatically in Android? Does the app need to be a System app to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [removeAccount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#removeAccount%28android.accounts.Account,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Cjava.lang.Boolean%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) in AccountManager to attempt to remove the account. Note that this method is not guaranteed to remove the account.

Additionally, the first Gmail account configured on the device is a sort of main Account, and I don't think you can completely remove it without a factory reset

Edit , Code to Clear All GMAIL Password :

```
            AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
            Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
            for (int index = 0; index < accounts.length; index++) {
                accountManager.clearPassword(accounts[index]);
            }
```

Comment: Ok , so Just Unlink/Clear Password of the Main Gmail Account i need to Create an Account Object then Call clearPassword() , this method is guaranteed to Work , for Example i can call getAccount() and clearPassword() on All Accounts

Comment: @SmokCol I can't guarantee that it'll work, especially since at least one Gmail account is considered to be the primary account on the device. You'll have to try it for yourself and see

Answer (score 0):

I think that this isn't a question "for professional and enthusiast programmers"..  however, in my device: settings -> Account and Sync -> myaccount gmail.com -> remove account